# Keeping a console application that will be ran using Task Scheduler updated

Tags: c#, deployment, console-application, publishing

I have a solution with a Web Application, Console Application (and Windows Service, but that's probably for another question).

Publishing and keeping the Web Application up-to-date is easy. I simply right-click `Publish` to publish initially or update the live version.

---

Currently to "publish" or update a console application I copy the release exe and files over to the live machine. In this way I can use the task manager to run the exe in the copied location.

This smacks of bad practice to me. The problem with doing a right-click, `Publish` on the console app is there's no easy way for the task scheduler to launch the exe. Additionally i'm not sure what would happen when it came to updating the application. Would the "An update is available" screen just sit there waiting for a user to click ok??

---

**What is the best way of easily publishing and keeping a console application up to date?**
Ideally something I only have to do from Visual Studio (2008). I'll need to be able to set up task scheduler and then forget about it (no need to do anything with task scheduler or click through anything when updating).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic deploy of applications partly sounds like [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).
You may not be interested in the TDD parts, so you can just focus on the tools that allow you to grab code from your repository (SVN for example), build it and deploy it automatically.

Personally, and based on personal experience, I would do this for backstage environments only, for production I would stick to copying exes manually (and keeping backups, of course!)

Comment: I'm not interested in *automatic* deployment, it's more being able to click one button within VS to deploy when I want rather than copying files about. If there's no easy solution and it's not recommended I'll just stick to copying exes, although that strikes me as more error prone than something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Personally for these server side executables I just copy the exes.  If you're updating them a lot and you want to ensure that you don't put them in the wrong folder or miss a file you could write a .bat script to do the copying for you so that you can just double click on it.

To be honest if you're deploying a new program so often that this is a major issue for you then I'd say you have a different problem.  You shouldn't be making changes to a production app all that often.  There might be something that's currently code driven that ought to be data driven such that you can make modifications that you need to your program by modifying your database, config files, etc. and not the code of the program.

Comment: Where we work here (not saying this is particularly good practice) is that we do little updates often. I'm not talking about once a day, but it could be one or two times a month for a few months for a given application. Just enough for it to be annoying. The changes aren't to turn something on or off, but to add extra functionality, as such I don't think data-driven is the answer.